# Time format change according to time settings of phone

Tags: android, time, time-format

I am having a string that returns both date and time from database as `2012-11-09 13:20:17`. Now I need to take the time from the database string and show the time like `13:20:17 pm` if the phone time settings is `24 hour` and if the phone time settings is `12 hour` I should show it as `01:20:17 pm`. The time format can be obtained by this line of code which shows whether its 24hr or 12hr

```
String timefrmt = Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.TIME_12_24);
SimpleDateFormat timesettingsFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
date="2012-11-09 13:20:17";
Date myDate=null;
try {
     myDate=timesettingsFormat.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
} 
if(timefrmt==null){
     timefrmt="hh:mm aa";
}
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat=new SimpleDateFormat(timefrmt);
String time=timeFormat.format(myDate);
```

The sample code which I have tried is above but its crashing. Can anyone help me find a way for this.
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Rosalie..you ve not posted the error you get...Maybe the logcat can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public static String dateFormateNote(String date) 
{   

    try {
          DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
          DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
          return df2.format(df1.parse(date));
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
          return date;
        }
}
```